# how to continuously switch textswitcher between two values every 2 seconds

Tags: android, multithreading, background, while-loop

I've looked at the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822666/how-do-i-make-android-app-which-do-something-every-x-second)  as well as the code [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html)   but I still can't seem to get my code to work right.    With the 2nd link, I can get a "timer" that counts up on the page, but with the first, my UI locks up.    What I'm trying to do is have a seperate thread that continually flips the text in a textswitcher every 3 seconds as long as the app is open.  I need it to switch between two values, and have tried something like the following:

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {


       public void run() {
           while(true){                                                             
                try {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
                       @Override
                       public void run() {

                          try {
                            mSwitcher.setText("ON");  
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            mSwitcher.setText("OFF");
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                       }
                    }
                    ); 

                }catch (Exception e) {
                    //tv1.setText(e.toString());
                }

             } 
                 }
             };
```

Where it will flip "on" or "off" every 2 seconds.   I also need to be able to update the text switcher content from the main UI, but haven't gotten to the point i can try and test that.   In addition to the above, I have also tried to use an Async Task:

```
      new AsyncTask<Void, Double, Void>() {
      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
          while (true) {
              mSwitcher.setText("ON");
                SystemClock.sleep(2000);
                mSwitcher.setText("OFF");
                SystemClock.sleep(2000);
          } 
      }     
  }.execute();
```

but this did not work either.

Comment: why not use a viewflipper with 2 textviews. And set the flipinterval to 2 seconds. The viewflipper can be used auto flip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using [timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html):

```
Timer timer = new Timer("desired_name");
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
    new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            //switch your text using either runOnUiThread() or sending alarm and receiving it in your gui thread
        }
    }, 0, 2000);
```

[Reference for runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29). You cannot update gui elements from non-ui threads, so trying to update it from `doInBackground()` method of `AsyncTask` will lead to error.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative easier method of achieving this is to use a `viewFlipper` rather than a `viewSwitcher`.  This allows you to do everything that you want using the XML layout alone:

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
    android:autoStart="true"
    android:flipInterval="3000">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/on_textview"
            android:text="ON" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/off_textview"
            android:text="OFF" />
</ViewFlipper>
```

To make it look slightly prettier, you can also define the animations to be used in the `viewFlipper`:

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
    android:autoStart="true"
    android:flipInterval="3000"
    android:inAnimation="@android:anim/fade_in"
    android:outAnimation="@android:anim/fade_out">
```

[AdapterViewFlipper Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterViewFlipper.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
Timer t = new Timer();
    TimerTask scanTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            mSwitcher.setText(isOn ? "ON" : "OFF");  
                            isOn = isOn? false : true;
                        }
               });
        }};

    t.schedule(scanTask, 0, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I change the UI, use the handler. Make the handler variable private to the Activity and call handler.sendEmptyMessage().

You can use thread or Async task to call the Handler.sendEmptyMessage(ON/OFF).

One more way is to use Handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed ( ) . By this handler invokes itself after every time the user has set in delayed value.