# i want to make My flashLight start and stop after regular interval

Tags: android, flashlight

I am new to android please guide me..

I have flash light application that enable and disable the flashlight it works correctly but i want make them blinking the flashlight after regular interval ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn on, and then turn off the flashlight at set intervals. One way could be to use a Handler/Thread/Runnable combination for timed actions.

Some reading:

[How do i make Android app which do something every X second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822666/how-do-i-make-android-app-which-do-something-every-x-second)

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html